# Data preprocessing of very unusual data

Tags: machine-learning, data-processing

I have a dataset with about 100k data and there I have a column with salary of people. I have only 8k cells with salary out of 100k cells. As you can see most of the cells of salary column are empty. Now among 8k cells, I have 500 cells with exactly 99k salary, 6 cells with 40k salary and 7 cells with 34k salary. Rest of the cells of 8k cells have salary with gradual decrease from 27k. So the total dataset of the column looks like this

```
500 cells => 99k 
6 cells => 40
7 cells => 34k 
7487 cells => gradual decrease of salary from 27k to 10k
92k cells => no data
```

Now, how can I handle this data?

Comment: It seems like you have it pretty well under control already.  What are you trying to accomplish, and how do you know it isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by under control. But there is a paper related with the dataset who got around 8% better result than me and only this column seems to be the reason to me. Other columns are pretty much straight forward.

Comment: I mean the same thing that you mean by handle, ie. it means nothing without some definition of what you hope to achieve.  What paper do you refer to, and how is its result 8% better than yours?